# Simple Injector - Inject url value into service constructor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am not sure if this is even possible, but here goes. I am using Simple Injector and injecting my service interfaces into my apiControllers.  All fine.

I have 1 controller that can be called using different urls, for example it can be called be using each one of these urls

```
http://localhost/api/company
http://localhost/api/contact
http://localhost/api/cabbage
```

Now I need to know what that last word is, and use this within my service.

Currently I have a simple interface, like so

```
public interface IMyService() {
    MyObject Get(long id);
}
```

And then my basic service which implements the service

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private IDbContext _context;

    public MyService(IDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public MyObject Get(long id) {
        // here i need that word!!
        return _context.Database.RawQuery("SELECT * FROM something WHERE Id = " + id);
    }
}
```

Now my generic api controller looks like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{myword}")]
public class MyController() {
    private IMyService _service;

    public MyController(IMyService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    public Get(long id) {
        var model = Mapper.Map<ObjectModel>(_service.Get(id));

        return Ok(model);
    }    
}
```

I am thinking it would be best if i could inject that word directly into my service. So i would have to change the service constructor to be like this

```
public MyService(IDbContext context, string theWord) {
    _context = context;
    // now I can store the word and use it in my service
}
```

I am new to Simple Injector, so not sure who, or even if you could inject that word on a per web request basis? So each time the controller is created, a new service would be injected, but that word could be different....

Is this possible, or maybe there is a better way about this that someone knows of?

As I said, I am using C#, ASP.NET WebApi and Simple Injector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am thinking it would be best if i could inject that word directly
>   into my service.

No, you should absolutely not do this. This `word` is a runtime value (it is request specific), and your object graph (the services you let Simple Injector build up) should not consist of any runtime data. Runtime data should flow through method calls.

I think @Trevor is on the right way, although I disagree with his implementation, because your business layer should not be hard-wired to your presentation framework.

Instead, you should place the retrieval of that word behind an abstraction, let's call it `IWordService`. This means that `MyService` will look as follows:

```cs
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private IDbContext _context;
    private IWordService _wordService;

    public MyService(IDbContext context, IWordService wordService) {
        _context = context;
        _wordService = wordService;
    }

    public MyObject Get(long id) {
        string word = _wordService.CurrentWord;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

With `IWordService` defined as follows:

```cs
public interface IWordService {
    string CurrentWord { get; }
}
```

This interface should obviously be located in your business layer assembly, or an assembly that your business layer depends on.

And using the code that @Trevor provided, we can create an ASP.NET specific implementation as follows:

```cs
public sealed class AspNetWordService : IWordService {
    public string CurrentWord {
        get {
            var requestUri = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
            var theWord = requestUri.Substring(requestUri.LastIndexOf('/'));
            return theWord;
        }
    }
}
```

This `AspNetWordService` is specific to ASP.NET and should obviously be placed inside your Web API project, or one of its related assemblies. Registration of this class is simple:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton<IWordService>(new AspNetWordService());
```

Perhaps, this `AspNetWordService` implementation might not do exactly what you wish, but it shouldn't be that hard to change it. And changing this class doesn't impact any part of the system.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
public class MyController() {
    private IMyService _service;

    public MyController(IMyService service) {
        _service = service;
    }

    [Route("api/{serviceName}/{id}")] //url: api/myService/10
    //restful [Route("api/service/{serviceName}/id/{id}")]  //url: api/service/myService/id/10
    public Get(string serviceName, long id) {
        var model = Mapper.Map<ObjectModel>(_service.Get(id));

        return Ok(model);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the request URL in the service method and figure it out from there:

```
public Get(long id)
{
    var requestUri = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
    var theWord = requestUri.Substring(requestUri.LastIndexOf('/'));

    var model = Mapper.Map<ObjectModel>(_service.Get(theWord, id));

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is there a way to put it in the constructor?  I ask because on this controller, i have more methods then just the Get method, and dont really want to have to pass in "theWord" on each method call